# How can I get the content of a div by php from another link

Tags: php, html

I would like to get the contents of a div with ID `content` using PHP, and write the contents to a text file.

Here is some code that I tried:

```
<?php 
    $html = file_get_content('www.example.com');
    $divContent =  $html->find('div#contentArea', 0)->plaintext;
    $file = fopen("newfile.txt", w);
    fwrite($file, $divContent);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

this code isn't working that says some file_get_content error..

also tried this one

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/')->plaintext; 
    $divContent =  $html->find('div#contentArea', 0)->plaintext;
    $file = fopen("newfile.txt", w);
    fwrite($file, $divContent);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: google web-crawler for php, thats what you need.

Comment: `<div id='content'>some@email.com</div>` .. you want some@email.com ..

Comment: actuly same as you say that is what i need but how can i do that.. see my answer and try to modify it more

Answer (score 1):

I have needed to do this on many occasions due to site maintenance and error logging. PHP Manual explains further http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

BASIC EXAMPLE

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents('example.html');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($page);
    $node = $doc->getElementById('thisone');
    echo $doc->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: this shows error failed to open stream and empty DOMdocument

Comment: @MültïThìnkër: Well, obviously you need to insert your target URL.

Comment: see my answer and try to modify it more.. :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

What error throwed by file_get_content ? Maybe it's source, of your problem.

For selecting I used [phpquery library](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

```
<?php
  $code = file_get_contents('http://some-url-here');
  $document = phpQuery::newDocument($code);
  $inner = $document->find('div.hentry')->html();
?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why not? As I meant, author need method to extract content from HTML document, this library can be used. But you right - it's better with some trivial example.

Comment: see my answer and try to modify it more :) thank you